# How to send hard-coded events to piwik via python script

Tags: python, matomo

I am working on using piwik as a tracker for vm usage. Thr plan is that every time a VM starts or shuts down, a custom request will be send to a piwik server and report a UUID and a few other variables.
I downloaded the https://github.com/piwik/piwik-python-api project that is supposed to allow a python script creation but I am preety stuck after that.

All the vms have an ip (something like 10.0.5.15 in my localhost for example) and I will have to use this access to send the requests.

Can anyone provide a link to a simple example of how to send anything to piwik?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piwik library is intended for a python web server such as Django. Unless you're planning on running a web server in your VMs, it will be of no use. That said, running a web server to send tracks to piwik seems to be overdoing it.

Piwik is simply calling a URL when it sends data to the server. It doesn't use POST, only GET. Therefore, it is simple enough to replicate the call in Python using a script that will call a URL: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html

The actual piwik URLs can be as simple as:

```
http://piwik.example.org/piwik.php?idsite={$IDSITE}amp;rec=1
```

This will start a single session in the piwik DB. The ID Site is the piwik ID of the website you're tracking.

[Source](https://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/#use-case-tracking-data-using-the-php-client)

Additional variables can be passed using this session tracker.

I would recommend passing the user id in the uid parameter or alternatively in _cvar if you need additional custom variables.

> uid — defines the User ID for this request. User ID is any non empty
>   unique string identifying the user (such as an email address or a
>   username). To access this value, users must be logged-in in your
>   system so you can fetch this user ID from your system, and pass it to
>   Piwik. The User ID appears in the visitor log, the Visitor profile,
>   and you can Segment reports for one or several User ID (userId
>   segment). When specified, the User ID will be "enforced". This means
>   that if there is no recent visit with this User ID, a new one will be
>   created. If a visit is found in the last 30 minutes with your
>   specified User ID, then the new action will be recorded to this
>   existing visit.

[Source](https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-api)

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Hello Forgetso,
thnak you for the answer it is very very helpfull indeed. I now need to set a custom variable manually since I am not using the jstracker. Do you have any leads on how to do this?

Comment: You would pass it using JSON in the URL as per the example at piwik's site.

`http://piwik-server/piwik.php?_cvar={"1":["OS","iphone 5.0"],"2":["Piwik Mobile Version","1.6.2"],"3":["Locale","en::en"],"4":["Num Accounts","2"]}`

Here you can see custom variables called OS, Piwik Mobile Version, Locale and Num Accounts. The __cvar value has _not_ been URL encoded in the example. You would need to encode the value before passing.

[Source](https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-api)